# Salesforce Sentiment analysis for SFSC case description field

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-einstein

I have a requirement to do sentiment analysis for cases generated by web-to-case. I need to do it one case at a time. I want to pass Case description as an input and in output I want response like Positive, Negative,Neutral etc.

There is an open Einstein API available - Link (https://api.einstein.ai/v2/language/sentiment). But it is about to retire soon.

Einstein Vision and Language (including Sentiment) will be retired in May of this year.  See the top of this article:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/analytics/einstein-vision-language/guide/einstein-language.html#einstein-vision-and-language-are-hipaa-compliant

Is there are other safe alernative available to do sentiment analysis ?

Einstein open AI is available but it is retiring soon.